# Zend Gdata Spreadsheets nonsensical column names

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I have a spreadsheet with numeric column headers. When I use a list feed to view these column names, I get nonsensical strings i.e. "_cpzh4" when I'm expecting "1". This is making it very hard to insert new rows. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without seeing and example of your code, but you should be able to use the getText(); method on your cell entry. this will give you the text data of the cell.

So example:

```
$listEntry->cell->getText();
```

Comment: It's all just boilerplate code.I can't use a listFeed because it ignores the header row.

Comment: The worksheet has, in addition to other headers, a column for each day of the month, with the day number as the header - 1..31. When I call getColumnName() on one of the listEntrys' Customs, I get the correct value for the non-numeric entries, but random strings for the numeric ones. I also can't use a cellFeed because I don't know ahead of time how many columns there'll be.

Comment: cant you use the min/max query to get the row you want, then iterate over that to get the contents of each cell, so if you know your day headers are in row 2 then you can use the $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery();
$query->setMinCol(1);
$query->setMinRow(2);
$feed = $spreadsheetService->getCellsFeed($query);

Comment: No, because CellFeeds work perfectly. I only get the nonsensical values when I use ListFeeds, and I need to use ListFeeds later on in the code.